# How to grab a date from a string in PHPUnit

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I'm trying to grab only the date from a string.

```
<div class="entry_details">
  <i>
    <br>
    Team: EntryPod Podium
    <br>
    Created at:
  <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--//
      var d = new Date(1346364356000);
      document.write(d.toString());
      //--!>
  </script>
    Thu Aug 30 2012 15:05:56 GMT-0700 (PDT)
  </i>
</div>
```

I want to grab only Thu Aug 30 2012 15:05:56 GMT-0700 (PDT) and store it in a variable

The code I have is

```
$test = $this->getText("//div[contains(@class, 'entry_details')]");
```

But it grabs EntryPod Podium Created at: Thu Aug 30 etc.....

Comment: why not output the string to a specific element, so that you can reference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//div[contains(@class, 'entry_details')]//text()[contains(., 'GMT')]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not that good with xpath yet. What is the dot in //text()[contains(., 'GMT')] for?

Comment: @Raymond The `.` references the current node (this works a bit like in a file system: the `..` references the parent node in XPath). *(Hint: `//div[contains(@class, 'entry_details')]` is equivalent to `//div[contains(./@class, 'entry_details')]`)*